# Scheduling a process in progress Database

Tags: job-scheduling, openedge, progress-db

can someone help me how can i schedule this kind of code in Progress Database in way to generate that file.csv everyday at specific hour ?

Thank you!

```
DEF STREAM st1.

OUTPUT STREAM st1 TO c:\temp\file.csv.

   PUT STREAM st1 UNFORMATTED 

                             SKIP.
 END.
OUTPUT STREAM st1 CLOSE.
```

Comment: You need to state what OS you're running first as they're different.

Comment: Windows server standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "in the database".  A 4gl procedure runs externally to the database and would use the OS job scheduler or other tool to trigger a script that runs your procedure.

If this is a unix OS then the natural solution is to use "cron".  A possible crontab entry might be:

```
0 23 * * * /usr/local/bin/myjob.sh >> /var/log/myjob.lg
```

Where myjob.sh might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
#

DLC=/usr/dlc
export DLC

$DLC/bin/_progres -b /db/dbname -p myjob.p
```

If it is Windows then you could setup a "scheduled task".  That task could run a BAT file that might look like:

```
@echo off

set DLC=c:\progress\openedge

%DLC%\bin\_progres -b \path\dbname -p \path\myjob.p > \logpath\myjob.log
```

You can setup a scheduled task using the GUI or with the "schedtask" command like this:

```
schtasks /CREATE /TN "Nightly" /SC DAILY /MO 1 /ST 23:55:00 /SD 01/01/2000 /TR \path\myjob.bat /RU userid
```